# how to use multi Item Type in JetPack-Paging3?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-paging

I want to use Multi Type in Paging3,but **PagingDataAdapter** only suport one generic paradigm. How to do it?Maybe there is some demo?

And I want to use it with Room.

Like in a RecylerView , there are two kinds of item.One is text content,another is image.

So I want to know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would have some kind of base class that is shared between both view types.

There is a nice sample here showing a progressive migration from single view type to the pattern with a second view type getting injected from `.insertSeparators`.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-transform#convert-ui-model